# Historical prices via API for major alts (not BTC)

Tags: bitcoind, client, litecoin, api

I am trying to build a small project of mine using historical prices for major alternative currencies such as LTC, DGC, MOON, TIPS, etc and so far I managed to collect only current prices of cryptsy API.

Which APIs provide historical data?

Comment: you might try http://www.programmableweb.com/search/bitcoin there are some nice API's there that might offer what you're looking for